# "IllegalStateException: database not open" - on screen orientation change

Tags: android, sqlite

I have "java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open" - when I change the screen orientation when upgrading database is in progress.
When version of my database changes, onCreate() of my SQLiteOpenHelper subclass is called. In this method I'm simply dropping previous tables, creating new ones and populating them with data. Database is quite big and data is read from file, so I'm populating the data in AsyncTask subclass.

So, here are the most important parts of my code. 
**Activity:**

```
 
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  ...
  private MyOpenHelper dbHelper;
  private SQLiteDatabase db;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  dbHelper = new MyOpenHelper(this);
  db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  ... 
  }

  protected void onDestroy() {
    if (null != db && db.isOpen() && !db.isDbLockedByOtherThreads()){
      db.close();
  ...
  }
 ...
 }
```

**MyOpenHelper:**

```
public class MyOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
  ...
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
     //drop... 
     //create...
      db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
       db.endTransaction();
    }       
     /* populate database with data */      
     SQLiteDatabaseInitializer dbInit = new SQLiteDatabaseInitializer(mContext, db, mDialogHost, "db.txt");
   dbInit.execute();
   }
```

I know that the problem is that when I change the screen orientation, db instance gets closed - in Activity.onDestroy(). But I have to close it eventually. What is the best approach here? Anyone experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try forcing the activity to a particular orientation so that it cant transition to the other orientation?

```
<activity android:name=".views.AfterActionReview" android:label="@string/app_name" 
                 android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.VIEW" /> 
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If that is problematic for the overall use of your app, consider moving the db update process to a new activity that you can safely lock to a particular orientation and then switch back to the other one when finished with the db update.

I think you may still face a similar problem if the user quits your app while your long running update is happening.

The additional activity might also give you a place to warn the user not to interrupt the activity while updating.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, addition activity sound like a good idea. I'm already displaying progress dialog, so user is informed about long operation in progress.  I'll give it a try and let you know if it works.

Comment: Ok, your idea with additional activity was really great. It works perfectly fine for me. Just small modification to mmeyer proposal: android:screenOrientation="landscape" does not prevent activity from being destroyed. To make sure your activity is not destroyed you need to handle configuration changes yourself, by adding this: android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation". Thanks very much for your solution! Regards!

Comment: ...and of course onConfigurationChanged() method needs to be overriden in Activity